# PSQLException handshake_failure with openjdk 1.8.0_312-b07

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8

I am running a postgresql database in version 11.9 and I was able to connect to it and execute sql statements with this code:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource");
String jdbcConnection = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:64000/db?user=foo&password=nope&ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnection);
```

Please note: since this is only for the local testing environment I am totally fine with the NonValidatingFactory and without SSL verification.

After updating the jdk to :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.21.0) (build 1.8.0_312-b07 suse-27.66.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

I always get this exception:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:446)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:140)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

**Question**:
How can I change the code to be able to connect to the database again without downgrading the JDK or changing the postgres settings?

**Additional information that might help**:

1. These ciphers are supported by my postgres instance:

```
SELECT distinct version, cipher FROM pg_stat_ssl;
TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
TLSv1.3,TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

2. I've seen that there are some changes at the default java cipher suites within openjdk 1.8.0_312:
   https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/f60ef263eb92

Comment: _"How can I change the code to be able to connect to the database again without downgrading the JDK or changing the postgres settings?"_ - The whole point is that you can't use deprecated ciphers because of security.  Assuming that's the source of the incompatibility, and given your constraints, the only course of action is to figure out how to re-enable the deprecated cipher on the Java client side.  That's what documentation is for, and you may find out that it's not possible.

Comment: @JimGarrison i can't find any deprecated ciphers in my setup. Do you mind to enlighten me what deprecated ciphers I shouldn't use?

Comment: Are you sure the PSql server has SSL enabled on port 64000? You get these questions because you didn't provide all the necessary troubleshooting evidence.

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. It worked fine in the past. All that recently changed was the jdk8 version.

Comment: Is there a nested exception? Is there anything in the PostgreSQL log?

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, this doesn't exactly answer the question, but I currently assume that it was in fact a bug in the IcedTea openjdk:

I changed the jdk from:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.21.0) (build 1.8.0_312-b07 suse-27.66.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

to

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

and it's working again.